# Solo quiero listar las imagenes pero tambien me lista las subcarpetas

Tags: php, javascript

Este codigo me lista todos los archivos y carpetas dentro de mi carpeta imágenes lo que yo quiero es solo listar las imágenes omitiendo las subcarpetas que tengo dentro de esa carpeta imagenes que condición me hace falta en el código.

```
 <?php
function listar_archivos($carpeta){
    if(is_dir($carpeta)){
        if($dir = opendir($carpeta)){
            while(($archivo = readdir($dir)) !== false){
                if($archivo != '.' && $archivo != '..' && $archivo != '.htaccess' && $archivo != '' ){
                    echo '<li><a target="_blank" href="'.$carpeta.'/'.$archivo.'">'.$archivo.'</a></li>';
                }
            }
            closedir($dir);
        }
    }
}

echo listar_archivos('img');
?>
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que quieres hacer, agrega mas información para así poder entender y ayudarte.

Comment: Listo Oswuell ahora si ayudame.

Comment: Pero. ¿Tus imágenes están todas en la misma carpeta?

Comment: si las imagenes estan en esa carpeta pero no quiero que aparezca el nombre de las subcarpetas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mejor detectar si es un archivo y si no es un archivo que comience con '.', que se muestre; en el último if iría algo cómo:

```
if (is_file($archivo) && substr($archivo, 0, 1) != '.') {
  echo '<li><a target="_blank" href="'.$carpeta.'/'.$archivo.'">'.$archivo.'</a></li>';
}
```

---

Se me olvidó especificar que al usar is_file, toca indicar toda la ruta del archivo entonces sería algo cómo

```
is_file($carpeta.'/'.$archivo)
```

ya que se supone que estamos en un directorio superior, abre un directorio hijo y toca detectar si cada uno de los items dentro de ese directorio es un archivo válido.

Comment: No me funciono Raziel de echo lo puse y ya no me muestra nada.

Comment: Ya edité mi respuesta, es que toca indicar la ruta completa del archivo incluyendo la carpeta o directorio en que se encuentre.

Comment: Listo men te la rifaste muchisimas gracias!